# Upload Multiple Image and after select images, show input field for each selected images Using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to save multiple images, after select images I want to show the Caption input field for each image. using asp.net mvc and jquery
how can I achieve this?

Comment: please post example and your attempts - this question is about asking suggestions not for seeking solutions

Comment: Thanks @KostiaMololkin for your suggestion. i have added the technology I m using.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially there is two things going on here or more depending how you look at it.

Client->Is this a browser? Application? You will have to use html and css to accomplish your User Interface if it is a browser or you will need to setup your application ui to achieve the labels.

ServerSide->You will need to determine this technology, java, php or a number of others.
On the serverside you will have to setup a service that can handle the upload using the serverside of your choice.

There are a number of choices for Content Management Systems that already accomplish what you need. I will not mention any here in fear of retribution for offering a bad solution. :D